# incompatible return type when attempting to return 2d array in c

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, return-type

I'm attempting to write a function that returns a 2 dimensional array. This code is supposed to return a list with the absolute paths of the input files.

```c
char** findFiles(char rawFileList[100][1000], int numFiles) {
    char (*absolutepaths)[1000] = malloc(1000 * sizeof(*absolutepaths)); 

    int count1 = 0;

    int files = numFiles; //unused

    while (count1 < numFiles) {
        if ((is_file(rawFileList[count1])) != 0) { 
            char *path = realpath(rawFileList[count1], NULL);
            strcpy(absolutepaths[count1], path);
        } else { //it is d
            listFilesRecursively(absolutepaths[count1]);
        }
        count1++;
    }
    printf("%s", absolutepaths[1]);

    return absolutepaths;
}
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
error: returning ‘char (*)[1000]’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘char **’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   68 | return absolutepaths;
```

I tried to resolve this issue but I have only drawn blanks so far. Any advice or help anyone can offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess with char** you're trying to return 1 value. So with char* you will return pointer to array.

Comment: You can't return an array in C. BTW the approach is wrong anyway, how could the caller of `findFiles` know how many files  have been found? Please [edit] and show how `findFiles` should be called.

Comment: @user3121023 Well, unused pointers will be NULL on the most common implementations, but the standard doesn't guarantee that a pointer with all bytes zero will compare equal to NULL.

Comment: `char **` and `char (*)[1000]` are incompatible types.  Pick a single type and use it in both places.  There are several other problems as well.

Comment: The amount of space allocated by `malloc` is incorrect. It should be `malloc(numFiles * sizeof(*absolutePaths)`.

Comment: @user3121023 And we should both have realized that the allocated block does not contain pointers. :-)

Comment: Returning a `void*` is usually the easiest solution. Not type safe, however. Alternatively, consider passing the array by reference and return through a parameter: `char (**rawFileList)[1000]`. Not pretty but type safe and less messed up that trying to return a pointer to array, after which the C syntax goes completely bananas. Yet another option is to typedef an array type, which isn't recommended for several other readability reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite common (not only for beginners) misunderstanding.

`**` pointers are not 2D arrays or pointers to arrays.

You need to return a pointer to the array or (if the size of the array is not known or passed as a parameter a pointer to `void`

```
int (*functionReturnninPointerToArray(int array[][100]))[100]
{
    /* .... */
    return array;
}

void* functionReturnninPointerToVLA(size_t cols, int array[][cols])
{
    /* .... */
    return array;
}
```

The first one can be also written as

```
typedef int array100[100];

array100 *functionReturnninPointerToArray(array100 *array)
{
    /* .... */
    return array;
}
```